# how to use super().__init__() method for 2 or more classes?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, superclass

Here I have provided an example to illustrate my problem when a class inherits from 2 classes, then the super method only calls the constructor of the first inherited class.

```
import inspect
class A :
    def __init__(self):
        self.atr1 = 'Foo1'

class B :
    def __init__(self):
        self.atr2 = 'Foo2'
        
class C(A,B) :
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

## This part is only for illustration purpose
fooObj = C()
for i in inspect.getmembers(fooObj):
    if not i[0].startswith('_'):
        if not inspect.ismethod(i[1]):
            print(i)
```

Output: ('atr1', 'Foo1')

Can someone please fix it in a way so that both constructors from A and B being called?
Note:

- I don't want to hardcode class A and B in C
- Class A and B are independent and don't inherit from each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `super().__init__()` in all the classes:

```
class A :
    def __init__(self):
        self.atr1 = 'Foo1'
        super().__init__()

class B :
    def __init__(self):
        self.atr2 = 'Foo2'
        super().__init__()
        
class C(A,B) :
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
```

This will cause C to call all `__init__` in its MRO, up to the `object` class empty init.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why do I see the atr1 in class B now?
I don't want A or B to inherit from each other.

Comment: There is no `atr1` in `B()` with the code I provided.